# C#について、関数の仮引数で、タプルの分解がしたい

Tags: c#, .net

例として、関数fは

```
int f ((int, string))
```

のような型を持つとします。

実際に関数fを定義するとき、

```
int f ((int x, string s) t) {
    return t.x;
}
```

のように、仮引数のタプルtは定義できます。

しかし、タプルtは大抵の場合、意味を持たず、名前が冗長になりがちです。
なので、例えば、

```
int f ((int x, string s)) {
    return x;
}
```

のように、関数fの仮引数でタプルの分解がしたいのですが、それは可能でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。近い将来、できるようになれば嬉しいですね : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#7.3の時点ではできないようです。
素直に関数内の先頭で下記のように書いて、分解する必要がありそうです。

```
(int x, string s) = t;
```